# How to create a similar function of fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

As you read in the title, I want to create a function like `fwrite`.
But I can't seem to get a function similar to `fwrite`. I tried this:

```
int mini_fwrite(void *buffer, int size_element, int number_element, MYFILE *file) {
    if (file->ind_write == -1) {
        file->buffer_write = mini_calloc(IOBUFFER_SIZE, 1);
        file->ind_write = 0;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < size_element * number_element) {
        ((char *)file->buffer_write)[file->ind_write] = ((char *)buffer)[i];
        file->ind_write++;
        i++;
        
        if (file->ind_write == IOBUFFER_SIZE) {
            if (write(file->fd, file->buffer_write, file->ind_write) == -1) {
                mini_perror("Error");
            }
            file->ind_write = 0;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

That's not what I want. I want writing, via a `write`, only be triggered when the `buffer_write` is full. Anyone have an idea ?

I started with a structure like this

```
typedef struct MYFILE {
    int fd;
    void *buffer_read;
    void *buffer_write;
    int ind_read;
    int ind_write;
} MYFILE;
```

and a function like `fopen`:

```
int IOBUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

MYFILE *mini_fopen(char *file, char mode)
{
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;

    MYFILE *fo;

    fo = (MYFILE *)mini_calloc(sizeof(MYFILE), 1);

    if (mode == 'r') fo->fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    else if (mode == 'w') fo->fd = open(file, O_WRONLY);
    else if (mode == 'b') fo->fd = open(file, O_RDWR);
    else if (mode == 'a') fo->fd = open(file, O_APPEND);
    else mini_perror("Error\n");

    if (fo->fd == -1) return NULL;
    fo->ind_read = -1;
    fo->ind_write = -1;
    fo->buffer_read = NULL;
    fo->buffer_write = NULL;

    return fo;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program? For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: Yes I tried with gdb but as there are function calls in all directions, it is unreadable ><

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand what your problem is specifically. The `mini_fwrite` function code does only write when `file->buffer_write` is full. However, there's an issue with data possibly being left over to write when you're finished. If you don't have this yet, then you should ensure that this is checked and taken care of prior to closing the file, as well as making sure that any remaining data is actually written (e.g., by ensuring the file is closed) before the program exits. If it's another issue, please update your question to make this explicit.

Comment: Have you tried reading an implementation of fwrite?

Comment: Simplify your program, create an actual [mre], whose `main` function *only* calls `mini_fopen` and `mini_fwrite`. Make sure that this program exhibits the problem you have and ask about. Then debug that little program only.

Comment: Thank you very much John! :) So yes, I will take this problem into account by creating a mini_fflush but for the moment that is not what I want. I want to copy the items into buffer_write and update the ind_write index. I want the write to be triggered when the buffer_write is full. I don't know if it's more explicit :/

Comment: Ok, Some programmer dude ! I'm going to try that, I'll be right back.

Comment: "I want writing, via a write, only be triggered when the buffer_write is full." What does the function do instead? How do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want writing, via a `write`, only be triggered when the `buffer_write` is full.

Your function does exactly that.  It allocates the output buffer if not allocated already and copies bytes one at a time to it, writing the contents when `file->ind_write` has reached `IOBUFFER_SIZE`.

Yet there are some problems:

- `open(file, O_WRONLY)` does not create the file if it does not already exist, you cannot create files with the current `mini_fopen` implementation.
- the prototype for `mini_fwrite` should be:

  ```
  size_t mini_fwrite(const void *buffer,
                     size_t size_element,
                     size_t number_element,
                     MYFILE *file)
  ```

  and the return value is the number of elements successfully written.
- `buffer_read` and `buffer_write` should have type `unsigned char *` to avoid the need for casts when accessing the buffer contents.
- `write(file->fd, file->buffer_write, file->ind_write)` may returns the count of bytes successfully written. This count may be less than `file->ind_write`, especially if the call was interrupted by a signal.  You should try again with the unwritten part of the buffer until everything is fully written or a return value of `0` or `-1` is produced by the `write` system call.
- writing the buffer could be moved to a different function called `mini_fflush()` which you would also call in `mini_fclose()`.
- you don't check for failure of `mini_calloc` to allocate memory.

Comment: Ohh ok, I realized my mistake. To test this function, I took a buffer that was not the size of buffer_write so I didn't understand why it didn't write anything. So the function works very well. Thank you so much ! :)